Visualization of trained weights from a SOM
over the last few weeks, I've been thinking about the best way to visualize the weights (codebook vectors, centroids) resulting from the training of a SOM with a large number of features in order to identify clusters.
One possible solution is to standardize or normalize the features in order to bring them into a certain value range. After training, the weights per feature can be displayed in a plot as polylines across all units of the SOM grid.
Do you have any other ideas to process or display the trained weights of a SOM for cluster identification?
PS: I use Python and MiniSom.
Thanks and all the best
